# Where can I find the rules for Game of Life 1991 UK version?

Tags: game-of-life

I have the Game of Life board game and lost the instructions. I found the 1977 & 1991 instructions online but they are not the same as my version.
On the box there is that mine is of 1992 but still the 1991 instructions version are completely different. My version has mostly yellow tiles, few orange and some red tiles. No blue or white or green or Life tiles at all. Nor Pay Day tiles.

I have some tiles stating Casino tiles, take X amount of money or risk it. But how can you risk it? My version is you have to pay $20 K to go to university. Other versions say $40 K and above.

Life insurance cost $25 K. I have no Automobile or Homeowners Insurance Policies.

The cards I have are: Bank Loans, Salary, Career & Status Symbol. (No House Deeds & Stock Cards)

**Where can I find the rules for this version?**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I haven't been able to find them online anywhere, but I believe I can narrow your search.

This particular box was marketed exclusively to Great Britain, which makes them less popular than most English versions which were aimed at US buyers. Thus it's likely no one ever bothered to upload a pdf version of the game. Although the copyright is 1992, it's called the 1991 UK edition.

You can verify that it is the Great Britain marketed version by checking the bottom left corner (assuming you're looking at it with University going left and Career going right, as you do in your photo) and seeing the characters 4560GB written vertically. It's quite small, but is just next to the Hurricane tile.

You can ask Hasbro themselves for the rules to this edition at their customer service website at https://hasbro-new.custhelp.com/app/utils/login_form/redirect/ask (note, a login is required) or you can write them at

> Hasbro UK Ltd
>   PO BOX 43
>   Newport
>   Gwent
>   NP19 4YH

I hope this helps focus your efforts on finding the rulebook appropriate for your game!

Comment: Thanks so much! Yes exactly the version I have is the one you mentioned. Correct regarding the 4560GB written vertically.

Comment: I tried to to get in touch with North america chat of Hasbro before I submitted the question here but regretfully they do not have instructions for this particularly version. 
Actually after trying everything without success, I tried to search on ebay and there were about 4 or 5 selling that same version. To be frankly I didn't want to buy the game as I already have, I just wanted the instructions. I sent a msg to each seller and explained to them what I needed and if it's possible to just send me instructions.

Comment: Thankfully I found a good hearted seller and they took a pic of each page of the instruction and sent them to me. Bless their heart! .... 
Tho I have still followed your suggestion and logged into the UK site and sent them a msg explaining what I need....  Now awaiting their reply..... I can now enjoy playing the game which was so dear to me in my childhood. Thanks again from the bottom of my heart! ... Merry Christmas!

Comment: @ElinorVella can you upload those pictures somewhere so we can use them as a reference for future visitors to our site? It would be great if others with your problem can find the solution here.

Comment: Yes sure, with pleasure! ... Let me tell you what I'm gonna do ... I will type all the instructions myself in word documents since I don't want to copyright other people photos as we all know that is illegal, then I'll get back to you to let you know what should I do to post them. I will do them when I have a chance.

Comment: Excellent, that was going to be my next suggestion. I was surfing EBay trying to find a good version to do just that, but it was like 4am my time so I had to get to bed. :)

Answer (score 3):

I have the exact same version, (4560GB), and also lost the instructions from the box! Most of the instructions for the game online were all for a different version, referring to life tiles, payday and different coloured spaces, car insurance and things like that, all which didn't make sense.

After much searching I finally found instructions that make sense for *this* version:

[image: game of life 4560GB 1991 UK edition instructions]

N.B. My version obviously does not have them printed on the box like in this photo (would have been useful!), so it is presumably from a very slightly different print run. But, everything here from these ones makes sense for the 4560GB edition of the game (and states this version in the bottom right of the lid), and was how I remember it playing from when I was younger.

Hope this helps someone else wanting to experience a bit of nostalgia!